# How can I declare my Java WebSocket endpoint to consume and produce JSON?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, websocket, jsr356

How can I convey the information in a declarative way that I need my  JSR 356 supported WebSocket server endpoint  to consume and produce JSON payload?

If not possible declaratively,  what is programmatic way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No direct annotation for JSON, but you can use:

```
@ServerEndpoint( value = "/websocket", 
  encoders = { JsonEncoder.class },   
  decoders = { JsonDecoder.class })
```

JsonEncoder, JsonDecoder are classes which implements Encoder.Text, Decoder.Text interfaces.  You can find sample here: [Java EE HTML5 WebSockets Encoder and Decoder example](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-html5-websockets-encoder-and-decoder-example)